# PhP ведет себя неадекватно

Tags: php

Всем привет , есть скрипт который читает образец , ищет тотже самый текст в самом себе , находит и заменяет его на пустую строку.

Все работает на ура , только вот иногда какие - то баги возникают , не могу понять в чем проблема , если скрипт не трогать и не редактировать все на ура , но когда например я от руки добавляю туда какие - то функции , (При этом не трогая саму строку поиска и замены) , он отказывается удалять из себя информацию по образцу.
Код довольно большой , но я его выложу , может я упустил что - то.

```
$variable = $_POST['deleten']; //пост запрос на удаление текста
$value = 'deleten';  //значение запроса на удаление
$admfile = 'admintoursample.php'; //образец админки
$pagefile = 'toursample.php'; //название страницы
$contfile  = 'content/contentsample.txt'; // контент с названием изображения
$contfile2 = 'content/contentsample2.txt'; //контент2
$contback  = 'content/contentsample2back.txt'; //backupконтента
$contimage = file_get_contents($contfile); //читает название изображения
if ($variable == $value) { //если значение совпадает с именем post запроса
$admlist = 'adminpan.php'; //админ панель куда записывается
$admcont = file_get_contents($admlist); //читаем
$admstring = '<p><a href="admintoursample.php">toursample.php</a></p>';
$admcontold = array("$admstring"); //читаем строку из файла страницы если в админке есть такаяже строка заменяем ее на пустую строку ""
$admcontnew = array("");
$admphrase  = str_replace($admcontold, $admcontnew, $admcont);
if(file_put_contents($admlist, $admphrase)) {
    echo "succes page\n";
}
unlink($admfile); //удаляем ненужные файлы , так как удаляем страницу
unlink($pagefile);
unlink($contfile);
unlink($contfile2);
unlink($contback);
unlink($contimage);
echo "Successfuly removed";
$partext = 'resettext.txt'; // текстовый файл с php кодом
$parfile = 'reset.php'; // главный файл куда записываются данные после создания страницы , и он их исполняет если понадобится , и при удалении сравнивает текст из 'resettext.txt' и у себя , если есть совпадения удаляет из себя строку которая совпала
$parfilecont = file_get_contents($parfile);
$partextcont = file_get_contents($partext);
$parcontold = array($partextcont);
$parcontnew = array("");
$parphrase = str_replace($parcontold, $parcontnew, $parfilecont);
if(file_put_contents($parfile, $parphrase)) {
unlink($partext);    
echo "succes reset remove";
}
else {
echo "/";
}
$cretext = 'creatortext.txt'; //тоже самое что выше , только этот скрипт занят другой работой , но смысл один и тотже , поиск замена и удаление.
$crefile = 'creator.php';
$crefilecont = file_get_contents($crefile);
$cretextcont = file_get_contents($cretext);
$crecontold = array($cretextcont);
$crecontnew = array("");
$crephrase = str_replace($crecontold, $crecontnew, $crefilecont);
if(file_put_contents($crefile, $crephrase)) {
   unlink($cretext);
   echo "succes creator remove";
}
else {
    echo "/";
}
$selftext = 'deletetext.php'; //тоже самое что и выше.
$selffile = 'delete.php';
$selffilecont = file_get_contents($selffile);
$selftextcont = file_get_contents($selftext);
$selfcontold = array($selftextcont);
$selfcontnew = array("");
$selfphrase = str_replace($selfcontold, $selfcontnew, $selffilecont);
if(file_put_contents($selffile, $selfphrase)) {
unlink($selftext);    
echo "succes self remove";
}
}
else {
    echo "/";
}
```

Comment: Для начала отформатируйте код, и внесите короткие комментарии в код.

Comment: Честно говоря, не удивительно, что при внесении изменений в индусский код, что-то может сломаться.

Comment: щас напишу комментарии

Comment: При добавлении , даже просто echo 'hello' , в код , str_replace перестает работать , и он отказывается что - то из себя удалять

Comment: Может ли быть проблема в правах доступа? У меня ubuntu . и пхп стоит на модуль апача , когда сам создает файлы дает им права только для www , а этот файл доступен всем , возможно есть какойто конфликт?

Comment: Нет , проблема именно в скрипте .. пытаюсь наладить пока что

Comment: Этому коду срочно нужен рефакторинг, одна функция сократит простыню в десять раз.

Comment: да , я в курсе , но так как времени уже мало , мне нужно решить проблему с тем что str_replace отказывается заменить строку если в код внесены изменения (вообще не касаемые заменяемой строки) , пока только выяснил что проблема изза кода , но в чем именно пока не могу найти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена , дело было в расширении файла.
переименовал `deleteexample.txt в ---> deleteexample.php` , и при добавлении кода , str_replace работает нормально , хотя в этом файле хранится только текст , весьма непонятное поведение функци.

Спасибо тем кто пытался помочь

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне проще провести рефакторинг и разбираться в нечто подобном, чем в том, что есть на данный момент у Вас. К тому же это занимает не так много времени, а плюсы просто огромные. Пройдитесь по строкам под дебагером, что бы отловить момент, когда возникают ошибки.

```
if ($_POST['deleten'] == 'deleten') { 
    ReplaceContent('adminpan.php', '<p><a href="admintoursample.php">toursample.php</a></p>', true);

    UnlinkPages();

    ReplaceContent('reset.php', 'resettext.txt');
    ReplaceContent('creator.php', 'creatortext.txt');
    ReplaceContent('delete.php', 'deletetext.php');
} else { echo "/"; }


function UnlinkPages()
{
   $unlinkList = [
       'admintoursample.php',
       'toursample.php',
       'content/contentsample.txt',
       'content/contentsample2.txt',
       'content/contentsample2back.txt',
       file_get_contents('content/contentsample.txt')
   ]; 

   foreach($unlinkList as $link)
   {
       unlink($link);
   }
   echo "Successfuly removed";
}

function ReplaceContent($selffile, $selftext, $noContent = false)
{
   $filecont = file_get_contents($selffile);
   $textcont = $noContent ? $selftext : file_get_contents($selftext);
   $phrase = str_replace([$textcont], [""], $filecont);
   if(file_put_contents($selffile, $phrase)) {
       unlink($selftext);    
       echo "success " . $selffile;
   }
   else
   {
       echo "error " . $selffile;
   }
}
```

Comment: спасибо , а какой дебаггер посоветуете ? Я просто еще не пользовался им

Comment: @S1lllver, я обычно пользовался дефолтным xDebug, но может найдете [что-то более подходящее](https://habrahabr.ru/post/210202/).

Comment: Я нашел в чем проблема , проблема в apache , потому что я запустил тотже скрипт , создав файлы от руки , и даже после внесения изменений str_replace работает на ура , осталось понять почему когда создает файл и дает права только www на изменение и редактирование 'deletetext.php,  При редактировании delete.php скрипт отказывается работать , хотя права на delete.php даны всем