# Помогите с str_replace очень странная ситуация

Tags: php, строки

Всем привет , есть 3 файла
`testcrea.php` //читает testexample.php и записывает в testtext.php и test.php 
`test.php`//читает testtext.php если есть совпадения в себе , заменяет на пустую строку
`testexample.php`//шаблон с указанным текстом

Проблема в том что все работает , но стоит зайти в test.php и добавить
например `echo 'ok';` , и test.php перестает работать при запуске будто str_replace даже и нет в коде , хотя я саму строку поиска и замены совершенно не трогаю.

Вот код

testexample.txt

```
$selftext = 'testtext.php';
$selffile = 'test.php';
$selffilecont = file_get_contents($selffile);
$selftextcont = file_get_contents($selftext);
$selfcontold = array($selftextcont);
$selfcontnew = array("");
$selfphrase = str_replace($selfcontold, $selfcontnew, $selffilecont);
if(file_put_contents($selffile, $selfphrase)) {  
echo "succes self remove";
}
```

testcrea.txt

```
<?php
$delete = 'test.php';
$exampledel = 'testexample.txt';
$exampled = file_get_contents($exampledel);
$fulldeletetext = 'testtext1.php';


// Delete
$delold1 = array("testtext");
$delnew1 = array("testtext1");
$delphrase1 = str_replace($delold1, $delnew1, $exampled);
if(file_put_contents($delete, PHP_EOL . $delphrase1, FILE_APPEND)) {
    echo "succesdelete\n";
}
if(file_put_contents($fulldeletetext, $delphrase1)) { //запись в deletetext.php (тогоже контента что и в delete)
    echo "succesdeletetext\n";
}
```

test.php (пустой , ожидает записи в него , чтобы после запуска проверить есть ли похожая строка в testtext , если да то удалить из себя эту строку

```
<?php

/* ------  BEGIN SCRIPT WORKING  -----------*/
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575545/php-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be дубликат вроде

Comment: да , только я нашел конкретную проблему в скрипте , вот и написал новый

Comment: Ну так всё ясно вы добавляете `echo 'ok'` и нет совпадения по шалбону. зачем вам ттакой жуткий алгоритм?

Comment: нет , echo 'ok' я добавляю до самой строки поиска/замены , он не должен так делать

Comment: Неужели не один php developer не может понять в чем тут проблема ? 
Я уже часа 3 над этой проблемой сижу..

Comment: содержимое testtext где где echo добавили

Comment: содержимое testtext , такое же что и test.php

Comment: в любом случае , str_replace должен заменять строки которые нашел в файле , не обязательно что бы файлы совпадали полностью

Comment: Ну а что вы ожидаете когда добавляете `echo` в test.php как вам str_replace сработает test.php и testtext.php станут разными.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: str_replace заменяет вхождения подстроки , даже если у вас разное содержимое файлов , если str_replace найдет строку в указанном файле , она ее заменит в любом случае

Comment: echo я добавляю не в искомую строку , а вообще поверх искомой строки , он не имеет отношение к поиску и замене

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена , копал так глубоко что почти дошел до китая , а проблема была в расширении файла .txt , сменил на .php и заработало нормально интересная ситуация либо баг с str_replace.